# Error Lighthouse returned error: generic::internal: APP::1: Abnormal renderer termination, status = crashed exit_code = 1

Tags: pagespeed, pagespeed-insights

While checking the website speed at [Here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fbankrotpluse.ru%2F)

It throws this error:

> Lighthouse returned error: generic :: internal: APP :: 1: Abnormal
>   renderer termination, status = crashed exit_code = 1

Please can anyone tell me how this can be solved and how serious is it?

Answer (score 1):

Your website has a problem with its SSL certificate.

What (I am making an educated guess here) is happening is that Lighthouse is attempting to run the 'redirects to HTTPS' test and is throwing an error within Chrome in 'headless' mode (the browser it uses to run tests) as the site does seem to try to redirect but then fails due to a certificate problem.

Fix your SSL certificate and the site should run through PSI fine.

You can use lighthouse (the engine used by Page Speed Insights) under the 'Audits' tab of Developer Tools (F12) within Google Chrome to get your results.

I ran Lighthouse and it worked fine.

Comment: thank you for your advice!

there’s still such a moment, there’s no SSL certificate for this domain at all and has never been, also on the same hosting there is another site with the same settings, and also without SSL at all, but it is being tested
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fgk-zdt.dev.dialtest.ru
how can this be? in fact, then, on all sites without an SSL certificate, should there be such an error?

Comment: sorry learned something new today about SSL, I thought if it showed a certificate if you tried to force SSL that there was a certificate issued for the domain, apparently it is not the case it will pick up any other domains certificate on that IP. Something is causing Lighthouse (the engine behind PSI) to fail. Use developer tools version as it will give you similar results as per my answer. I can't see anything obvious that would cause this.

Comment: Actually just try disabling your robots.txt temporarily - long shot but I can see you have /bitrix/ blocked and that contains CSS and JS files. Really doubt it but you never know.

Comment: the problem was the size of the logo))) http://joxi.ru/nAyn5BkIg3wGRr (when the client has not read the instructions and climbed to fill in the content)

Comment: Interesting bug, what size in MB was the file as I find it surprising that was an issue (I didn't even bother to look at the network tab as it happened so early in the audit).

Comment: Glad you got it sorted in the end