# Page Speed Insights error "generic::internal: APP::1: Abnormal renderer termination, status = crashed exit_code = 1"

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, performance, pagespeed-insights

When trying to run analysis for our customer web page: https://sklep-plcspace.pl/, we got an error from https://pagespeed.web.dev/:

generic::internal: APP::1: Abnormal renderer termination, status = crashed exit_code = 1

Javascript console looks good, no error found when inspecting, but still we cannot make an analysis.

Any reasonable cause?

I've checked console for errors, checked query monitor, but have no idea about what is potential conflict.

Comment: You're asking about a third-party API, have you contacted the software vendor for more information? Please read as well: [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: If you're wondering about the procedure, see such an exemplary report: https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/212792183/lighthouse-returned-error-generic-internal-app-1-abnormal-renderer-termination-status-crashe?hl=en , the only related Q&A I could find does not cover your domain, but I'll close against it anyway. https://stackoverflow.com/q/58112927/367456 -- When you found the answer for your case, you can answer there, as those are Q&A'ed by the error message. Let me know if you have any feedback or questions.